# How to give different attributes to new objects' and how __init__ exactly works?

Tags: python

All the objects get different random name variables but all of them have same random sex.
How this could happen?
How to make all the objects to have different random sex variables?
Am I using `__init__` correctly and what for I have to add to my class methods?

I am making a game with a population (list of objects) of people (objects from villager class). I want them to get random sex and Class gives each object random name from names list based on sex.

But something went wrong and sex is constant from the beginning. However, names are different!

Could you please help to solve this problem and suggest more relevant literature?

```
import random

mnames = ['Ivan', 'Oleg', 'Kirill']

fnames = ['Katya', 'Masha', 'Olga']

population = [1,1,1,1,1]

class villager:
    age = 0
    sex = random.randint(0,1)
    name = ''


    def __init__(self, sex = 10):
            self.sex = random.randint(0,1)


    def __init__(self, name = ''):
        if self.sex == 0:
            self.name =  mnames[random.randint(0, len(mnames)-1)]
        if self.sex == 1:
            self.name =  fnames[random.randint(0, len(fnames)-1)]

populsize = len(population)

for i in range(populsize):
    population[i] = villager()

for i in range(len(population)):
    print(population[i].sex, population[i].name )
```

I expect to see something like this:

```
1 Katya
0 Ivan
0 Ivan
0 Kirill
1 Olga
```

Actual result are (always same sex, first number ):

```
0 Kirill
0 Ivan
0 Oleg
0 Oleg
0 Oleg
```

or

```
1 Olga
1 Katya
1 Masha
1 Olga
1 Katya
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't allow you to overload `__init__` like you would in C++. The second definition of `__init__` in the class overwrites the first definition.

In your code, the class level variable for `sex` never gets changed. These class-level definitions aren't needed.

```
class villager:
    #these aren't needed, better to set in __init__()
    #age = 0
    #sex = random.randint(0,1)
    #name = ''

    #this definition is overwritten by the next definition of __init__()
    def __init__(self, sex = 10):
            self.sex = random.randint(0,1)
```

The proper way to define your class is:

```
class villager:

    def __init__(self, sex=10, name=''):
        self.sex = random.randint(0,1)
        if self.sex == 0:
            self.name =  mnames[random.randint(0, len(mnames)-1)]
        if self.sex == 1:
            self.name =  fnames[random.randint(0, len(fnames)-1)]
```

Since both `sex` and `name` aren't used by your code, you don't need to specify them in the `__init__` method. If you do want the option of setting them when you instantiate a `villager`, but also want them to be optional, you could code it like this:

```
class villager:

    def __init__(self, sex=None, name=None):
        if sex is not None:   # must be specific because you define sex as 0,1
            self.sex = sex
        else:
            self.sex = random.randint(0,1)
        if name:
            self.name = name
        else:
            if self.sex == 0:
                self.name =  mnames[random.randint(0, len(mnames)-1)]
            if self.sex == 1:
                self.name =  fnames[random.randint(0, len(fnames)-1)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understood, but how to change all the attributes in single __init__?

Comment: Great! Now it is working! Thank you for your detailed reply and this brilliant and simple solution!
P.S. Sorry if I am behaving myself wrong or strange. I have just registered here and I do not know all the rules and traditions.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have defined a class level attribute

```
class villager:
    sex = random.randint(0,1)
```

This ensures that all instances of `villager` will have a `.sex` attribute that is assigned with a single default value randomly at its definition.

You then define a `__init__` method that specifies `sex` as a parameter (which is ignored) but then assigns a random number regardless.

```
    def __init__(self, sex = 10):
```

Then it is redefined again thus shadowing over the first definition:

```
    def __init__(self, name = ''):
```

The second definition doesn't assign a `self.sex` attribute, thus every new instance of this class will fall back to the class level attribute (which was assigned once).  This resulted in exactly what you were seeing, where all the villagers have the same `sex` assigned.

In Python, you cannot have multiple definitions of the same method constructed in this manner (it kind of can through the use of a specific decorator, but you don't really need it here).  The quickest fix is to combine the two separate `__init__` into a single definition, and also implement what your intention might be:

```
class villager:

    def __init__(self, sex=None, name=None):
       if sex is None:
           self.sex = random.randint(0,1)
       else:
           self.sex = sex

       if name is not None:
           self.name = name
       else:
           if self.sex == 0:
               self.name = mnames[random.randint(0, len(mnames)-1)]
           elif self.sex == 1:
               self.name = fnames[random.randint(0, len(fnames)-1)]
```

So for this case, your default constructor should work

```
>>> v = villager()
>>> v.sex
1
>>> v.name
'Olga'
```

You can now also assign specific values in your constructor:

```
>>> v1 = villager(name='Gangut')
>>> v1.name
'Gangut'
>>> v1.sex
1
```

Or directly with both arguments

```
>>> v2 = villager(name='Elena', sex=1)
>>> v2.name
'Elena'
>>> v2.sex
1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation and further suggestions!